# Is there a way to relate the real numbers mod 1 to quotient groups?

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

My group theory textbook gives the following definition for the *real numbers mod 1*

> Let $G = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 0 \leq x < 1\}$ and for $x, y \in G$ let $x + y$ be the fractional part of $x + y$ (i.e., $x + y = x + y - [x + y]$) where $[a]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $a$)

At first I thought this will just be $\mathbb{R}/[0, 1]$ but this is nonesense because $[0, 1]$ is not even a subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}, +)$. Is there any way to define the real numbers mod 1 in terms of quotient groups (or any other concept if it helps provide insight)?

Comment: $(G,+)$ is (isomorphic to) the quotient group of $(\Bbb R,+)$ by the subgroup $\Bbb Z$. (This is analogous to the isomorphism between $(\{0,1,\dots,n-1\},+\bmod n)$ and the quotient group of $(\Bbb Z,+)$ by the subgroup $n\Bbb Z.$)

Comment: To elaborate on @AnneBauval's comment, $[0,1]$ (or more accurately $[0,1)$, no need to double-count the endpoints) isn't the *subgroup we're modding out by* but rather *a canonical set of representatives of the quotient group* that we get when we mod out by the right thing.